# Delete data series from existing xy graph

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I would like to create a code that deletes a data series from an existing xy chart on the sheet.
but i dont know how what is wrong with this code. someone please help me.

```
Dim srs As Series
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
With ActiveChart
    For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
        If .Name = c Then
        .SeriesCollection(srs).Delete
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: What is "c" in the IF statement? Is it a string?

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Is the `For Each`-loop iterating over all `.SeriesCollection`? Have you checked if  `Name` is matching `c` (whatever that is)? Is the `Delete`-Statement hit or not?

Comment: Sorry Im just new to programming and I the "c" variable stores a string from a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use With [Object] ... End With, all dot methods or properties in effect will be appended to that [Object]

```
With ActiveChart
    For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
        If .Name = c Then
        .SeriesCollection(srs).Delete
        End If
    Next
End With
```

In effect, that will become:

```
For Each srs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    If ActiveChart.Name = c Then
         ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(srs).Delete
    End If
Next
```

I think ActiveChart.Name is not the intended property to compare from in your IF statement.

You may try "srs.Name = c" in your IF and "srs.Delete" inside that like so:

```
With ActiveChart
    For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
        If srs.Name = c Then
           srs.Delete
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Please tell me if it works.

Comment: thank you very much sir. I tried the code and it worked. Your answer is very helpful
I am new to this so i am very happy to know my mistakes. :)

Comment: @GilbertCastro, you're welcome. Are you a kabayan? :-)